# Return specific data from mysql string

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to fetch some info from my database, and choose which of the info in the string, I want to display.

**--- What I know so far ---**

This code is showing me `NULL` value:

```
$ticketis = mysql_query("SELECT `module` FROM games ORDER BY `id`  DESC LIMIT 1,1");
$showticket = mysql_fetch_assoc($ticketis);
$rest = mb_substr($showticket,0,30);
var_dump($rest);
```

AND this code is showing me the data-string I want to cut out specific data from:

```
$ticketis = mysql_query("SELECT `module` FROM games ORDER BY `id`  DESC LIMIT 1,1");
$showticket = mysql_fetch_assoc($ticketis);
var_dump($showticket);
```

This is the return value of the above code:

> array(1) { ["module"]=> string(11) "0.435264836" }

What I want is to cut out is the numbers and display these: 0.435264836

Anyone got a clue what I can do to make that happen?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a note, if by "the number" you are talking about the `11` in `string(11)`, that's just a [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) thing (it's the length). You can try [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to see it differently: `print_r($showticket);`.

Comment: Do you want to display just the "numbers"? Because your code does display numbers. It displays those numbers as a __string__, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. And yes, I just want to display the number, actually after the dot, so that I in this case would be printing 435264836.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `$showticket['module']`

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an array, not just a single value. Since you're using `mysql_fetch_assoc` you get an associative array indexed by the column name, hence the `['module']`. If you would use `mysql_fetch_row` you'd get a numeric index and thus have to use `$showticket[0]`.

But please don't forget that all the mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP!

Comment: You should write why the user should use this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It seemed I had to use print_r to get the pure numbers from the string. My code ended up like this, combining Remo and FirstOne's suggestions. Thanks.

```
$ticketis = mysql_query("SELECT `module` FROM games ORDER BY `id`  DESC LIMIT 1,1");
$showticket = mysql_fetch_assoc($ticketis);
print_r($showticket['module']);
```

Comment: You don't need `print_r` here. It's only required if you want to show the details of a complex type like an array. In your case you want to show a discrete value in which case it's enough to use `echo` or `print`